# Accessing DB through Server or directly from app

Tags: android, sql-server, client-server

I am developing an app which needs to interact with an external DB (select, insert etc...)

I am considering whether i should use a server which will manage the DB access or access the DB directly from the app.

1. There could be tens of requests to the DB simultaneously (Multiplayer game)
2. Performance is a very important issue.

People tell me i should use a server and i ask why? what are the cons and pros? if doing so via a server i need to build json or xml responses and parse them in my which takes a bit of time.

This is really an architecture question, please vote for closing it.

Comment: Make your decisions based on keeping to a minimum on the mobile device: code, cpu usage, and web bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider the chosen answer here: [Connecting to SQL database directly or through a client-server service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005831/connecting-to-sql-database-directly-or-through-a-client-server-service)
which, though it does not pertain to android, answers your question in general and concludes in favor of creating a server-side application to manage databases.